# Preserve Leading and Trailing Spaces in Contact Name

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, custom-object

I have passed contact name with leading and trailing spaces but when I click on save the spaces are removed from the name.

Is there any way we can preserve spaces in Contact's Firstname and Lastname?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE! Don't think that it's possible to turn off this behavior.

Comment: have the source system convert the leading and trailing spaces to `&nbsp;` characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not UI behavior and is something salesforce is doing to all string fields at back-end because we do not have un-trimmed field value even during before insert. A fix or flexibility can only be provided by Salesforce